# how to get the folder from one container to another container using docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am using Docker Compose for multi-container application I have two docker-files one for tomcat and one for ant first tomcat docker file build successfully  and when the ant docker-file build my application it required tomcat/lib folder and tomcat/webapps 
which is present in another container so how i get the tomcat folder present in tomcat container in ant container so that my application will build successfully

now i am getting an error

tomcat/lib not found...

my docker-compose.yml :

```
version: '3'     
services:   
  ant:   
    build:         
      context: "."   
      dockerfile: dockerfile_ant      
    container_name: ant-container      
    volumes:
      - ant:/usr/local/tomcat:ro      
    links:
      - tomcat
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"      
  tomcat:    
    build:    
      context: "."
      dockerfile: dockerfile_tomcat    
    container_name: tomcat-container    
    volumes:     
      - ant:/usr/local/tomcat:rw          
    expose:   
      - 80   

volumes:   
  ant:
```

my dockerfile_ant:

```
FROM openjdk:6

MAINTAINER shri

ENV ANT_HOME /usr/local/ant   
ENV PATH ${PATH}:/usr/local/ant/bin    
ENV ANT_OPTS=-Dfile.encoding=cp1252    

ADD apache-ant-1.7.0 /usr/local/ant

ADD TemplateUI /usr/local/TemplateUI

WORKDIR /usr/local/TemplateUI    
ENV JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Dfile.encoding=cp1252

RUN ant
```

My dockerfile_tomcat:

```
FROM tomcat:6

ENV CATALINA_HOME /usr/local/tomcat  
ENV PATH $CATALINA_HOME/bin:$PATH  

RUN mkdir -p "$CATALINA_HOME"  

VOLUME ant

WORKDIR /usr/local/tomcat   

EXPOSE 8009
```

Please guide us in which way you can run your multi-container application using docker compose .

Thanks
shriyash

Answer (score 3):

this is the docker-compose.yml:-

```
version: '3.2'   
services:    
  ant:   
    build:        
      context: "."   
      dockerfile: dockerfile_ant  
    container_name: ant-container  
    links:  
     - tomcat   
    volumes:  
      - ant:/usr/local/tomcat:rw     
    ports:  
      - "8080:8080"        
  tomcat:   
    build:    
      context: "."  
      dockerfile: dockerfile_tomcat   
    container_name: tomcat-container   
    restart: always   
    volumes:   
      - ant:/usr/local/tomcat:rw   
    expose:   
      - 80   
volumes:     
  ant: {}
```

and no need to specify volume in ant-dockerfile  and tomcat-dockerfile

Answer (score -1):

You can define named volumes in compose file & share it across multiple containers by adding those volume names in `volume` section of compose file for each container.

Ref - https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes

Example (`logs` volume is shared across multiple containers )-

```
version: '3.2'

services:

  lr:
    build:
      context: ./docker-build
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.lr
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - logs:/rest/logs/

  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    volumes:
      - data:/data
      - logs:/rest/logs/

volumes:
  logs:
  data:
```

Alternatively, you can also you host bind/mount volumes as well but try not to use them(host-bind-volumes) as much as possible.

Comment: its not working...  your docker-compose.yml file is same as my docker-compose .yml  you just added one more volume..  and my que is how i get the tomcat folder from one container to other container.. to build my application

Comment: This works in my case. Can you remove `VOLUME ant` from Dockerfile & give it  a try.

Comment: no its not working....   in which way you get the tomcat folder or ant other folder  from volume to another container

Comment: Just the configuration in the compose is enough for that. It works as - `Volume created --> Attach volume to defined containers --> Whatever written inside volume gets synced across multiple containers`. Not sure what's missing in your case, i have been using the same way quite a while.

Comment: so in docker file how i will set the the ENV for tomcat which is present in the volume

Comment: ENV variables and Volumes are entirely different. Volume will keep your files, you can define ENV in Dockerfile or compose.

Comment: From my understanding above code makes docker engine create an empty volume (on the host) to be shared among other containers no matter what files existed on the containers' images.
So the solution could be to use above configuration but in entrypoint of your tomcat container, add commands to copy files to the shared volume. Then ant container will have access to those files. Obviously the shared mount point on tomcat container can not be where tomcat files are (in your case /user/local/tomcat).

Comment: Wondering if initializing shared volume from one of the containers can be done using dokcer or docker-compose built-in functions or configurations?

Comment: From https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-share-data-between-docker-containers (Step 3) realized that shared volume would be initialized if already existed on image of source container. So no need to mount into 3rd location and copy files from source container by commands in entrypoint. Not sure how docker handles this if both images contain files.